# Atualizar consulta com último input da tabela

Tags: php, jquery

Como faço para atualizar uma consulta com dados que foram inseridos no BD após a última consulta?

Exemplo simples é uma rede social: Você está visualizando os dados existentes, e quando existe uma nova postagem, esta é inserida no top da visualização atual.

Comment: Usando `SELECT [field] FROM [data_base].[dbo].[table] ORDER BY [filed] DESC` ou, no lugar de `DESC` usar `ASC`. Isso usando SQL Server, mas a cláusula `ORDER BY [field] ASC/DESC` é da linguagem SQL.

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida acho que não é bem isso apenas que ele quer saber. Essa consulta só ordena a tabela. Ele quer saber como verificar novas "atualizações" na tabela, via as linguagens informadas.

Comment: Nesse caso, ele só precisa usar um `set_timeout()` para requerer do banco de dados a cada X segundos ou minutos um nova atualização. Tudo feito por AJAX. VEr também HistoryJS. https://github.com/balupton/history.js

Comment: Em relação a consulta isto é tranquilo. Mas não consegui implementar um "flag" referenciando e salvando a hora da última consulta e quando usar o set_timeout() para a próxima consulta, coletar somente as novas entradas da tabela.